# Trying to write a stored function to be used in mysql UPDATE SET statement

Tags: mysql, function

I have two tables TABLE-2 and TABLE_3

- TABLE-2

```
Preferred_Name|name_TABLE_3
---------------------------
Pref_Name1    |
Pref_Name2    |
Pref_Name3    |
...etc
```

- TABLE_3

```
name
-----
name1
name2
name3
...etc
```

I am trying to use MATCH (name) AGAINST ('Preferred_Name') to update TABLE-2 with the best match name from TABLE_3 such as:

> SELECT `name`, MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('Preferred_Name') as relevance FROM `TABLE_3` WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('Preferred_Name') having relevance=max(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('Preferred_Name'))

But since AGAINST does not accept variables, I tried to do it through a stored function I am trying to write a stored function in phpmyadmin to be used in an UPDATE SET statement:

```
UPDATE `TABLE-2` SET `TABLE-2`.`name_TABLE_3` = best_fulltext_match(`TABLE-2`.`Preferred_Name`);
```

The inside code:

> SELECT `name`, MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('Preferred_Name') as relevance FROM `TABLE_3` WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('Preferred_Name') having relevance=max(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('Preferred_Name'))

works fine and display the correct query when one keyword is used at a time but when I execute the function I got no result.  Appreciate any help.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `best_fulltext_match`(`search_string` TEXT) RETURNS varchar(600) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT `name`, MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('search_string') as relevance FROM `TABLE_3` WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('search_string') having relevance=max(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('search_string'))); 
END
```

Comment: Perhaps a trigger would be more appropriate - would need more detail to say for sure.

Comment: @P.Salmon This sound like a good alternative option. What other information would you like to know

Comment: An expansion of ' to be used in an UPDATE SET statement to update TABLE-2' would be useful.

Comment: @P.Salmon I edited the post to include as much details as I can. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL functions return single value only, So rather than returning a whole table from a function, You should use Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `best_fulltext_match`(`search_string` IN TEXT)
CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
        SELECT `name`, MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (`search_string`) as relevance
        FROM `TABLE_3`
        WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (`search_string`)
        GROUP BY `name`
        HAVING relevance=max(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (`search_string`))); 
END
```